# Ingresar datos a la api desde mi formulario web

Tags: api, laravel-6, guzzle

Actualización: Por cierto, me agrega los empleados, es sólo que me manda ese error en vez de mandarme al index. (SOLUCIONADO, pasé el body a la variable jaja).

dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve:

```
public function create2(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/add',['body'=>'{"nombre":"Empleado2","apellidos":"Empleado2 Empleado2","correo":"Empleado2@gmail.cl"}']);
    $stream = $response->getBody();
    $contents = $stream->getContents(); // returns all the contents
    $datos['empleados']=json_decode($contents);
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' =>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/']);
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'user');
    $stream = $response->getBody();
    $contents = $stream->getContents(); // returns all the contents
    $datos['empleados']=json_decode($contents);

    return view('empleados.index',$datos);
}
```

buenas! el tema es que estoy conectando mi web con mi Api, pero para crear datos y modificarlos, debo pasarlos por la llamada de guzzle y me gustaría poder pasar los datos del formulario a la Api y de la Api a la web jaja no sé si se entiende, espero que si, muchas gracias!.( SOLUCIONADO ).

```
#hay que reemplazar:
$response = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/add',['body'=>'{"nombre":"Empleado7","apellidos":"Empleado7 Empleado7","correo":"Empleado7@gmail.cl"}']);
#por esto:
$response = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/add',['body'=>'{"nombre":"'.$request->nombre.'","apellidos":"'. $request->apellidos.'","correo":"'.$request->correo.'"}']);
```

Mis rutas Api:

```
Route::get('/user', 'ApiController@GetEmpleados');
Route::get('/user/{id}','ApiController@GetID');
Route::POST('/user/add','ApiController@AddEmpleado');
Route::get('/user/borrar/{id}','ApiController@DeleEmpleado');
Route::POST('/user/editar/','ApiController@UptEmpleado');
```

Mis rutas Web:

```
Route::post('/empleados/create2','EmpleadosController@create2')->name('empleados.create2');
Route::resource('empleados','EmpleadosController');
```

El controlador de mi web:

```
public function create2(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/add',['body'=>'{"nombre":"Empleado7","apellidos":"Empleado7 Empleado7","correo":"Empleado7@gmail.cl"}']);
    $stream = $response->getBody();
    $contents = $stream->getContents(); // returns all the contents
    $datos['empleados']=json_decode($contents);
    return view('empleados.index',$datos);
}
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es, a través de Guzzle, hacer el llamado a la Api para agregar los usuarios desde la web pero hacia la Api, espero haberme explicado bien xd.

PD: los usuarios me gustaría agregarlos desde el formulario, pero como ven debo agregarlos a través de la línea de código:

```
$response = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/add',['body'=>'{"nombre":"Empleado7","apellidos":"Empleado7 Empleado7","correo":"Empleado7@gmail.cl"}']);
```

Pero quisiera que los datos que se registraran en la Api fueran los de mi formulario Web y no a través de pasarle los datos por el controlador Api.

Muchas gracias!